# How different are the various Exchange Server versions?

Tags: windows, exchange

So basically I'm eventually going to have to do the maintenance of Exchange servers and I'm curious about how different the various versions are from each other since I'm going be learning how to do so soon.

Since I'll be learning about Exchange before knowing what version the customers I'll be supporting have, what version should I learn in order to have the broadest range of Exchange servers I can admin?

My spontaneous reasoning is to choose 2007 or 2010 because it should get me familiar enough to admin the later versions but also close enough to e.g. the 2003 version to manage (most of our clients have really, really old software in general so someone having 2003 wouldn't surprise me). Am I correct in this line of reasoning or would I have to learn several versions because they are vastly different? Or maybe I should master one and then just pick up a booklet on the customers specific version when they come along?

How different are the various Exchange servers from one another?

Comment: Exchange 2007 is also out of extended support (that means no more security patches).  :(

Comment: `How different are the various Exchange servers from one another?` - Getting an understanding of Exchange Server 2003 isn't going to help all that much in understanding later versions of Exchange. Exchange Server 2000/2003 are fairly similar. Exchange Server 2007/2010 are fairly similar. Exchange Server 2013/2016 are fairly similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exchange PowerShell is relevant for versions 2007 and later.  Depending on how deep you want to go, there are *many* differences.  In my opinion, 2010 and later have fewer differences than 2003-2007-2010.

My vote is Exchange 2010 is the oldest version you should try to focus on.  Aim for more current versions if possible, and I also recommend learning hybrid Exchange with Office 365.

- Database Availability Groups (Modern tech) are introduced, the basis of current availability architecture
- Public Folders (Legacy Tech) are still in fairly heavy use.  Respect and fear them.  Anyone who is still running legacy Exchange probably didn't do a great job setting up Public Folders to begin with.
- PowerShell support is robust, and the everyday cmdlets have not changed much since.

Answer (score 4):

A few things to consider also are the upgrade paths.

Exchange 2010 is the only version that supports coexistance and upgrade paths from 2003 (it also will support 2007).

Exchange 2013 and 2016 are practically identical in code/structure/UI.  If you're dealing with a lot of Legacy customers, I recommend 2010 as the overall PowerShell management is fairly mature in 2010 vs 2007 and hasn't changed much vs 2013, 2016/Exchange Online (O365).

2010 also has the Database Availability Group (DAG) high availability database structure, which is much improved over earlier architectures.